# OpenJDK7: What essential ADTs are not Implemented in OpenJDK7?

Tags: java, specifications, adts

What Abstract Datatypes should be added to OpenJDK7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at these two links you will see what some people feel is missing:

- http://commons.apache.org/collections/
- http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/

My favourite missing one is Bag... it is easy to implement, but annoying to have to implement it.

Mulimaps would also nice to have in the standard packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think they should stop adding new libraries to the JDK. You can easily get what you need from third-party, open-source libraries. Hopefully, with version 7 the JVM and its standard libraries will become more modular.

Comment: That depends, some thins, such as data structures, are fundamental, and it is nice to be able to rely on them being there.  For higher level constructs I agree with you though.

Comment: If they had decided this a few versions ago then many of the very nice concurrent data structures would not be as generally available, at least not with the same performance.  JVM hooks were necessary for their current performance level.